# jQuery: What is this structure?

Tags: jquery

What is the following structure called:

```
$('', { })
```

I see it often, for instance here from appending options to select elements:

```
$("#items").append($('<option>', { value : "mouthForWar" , text : "Pantera" }));
```

In the more general sense, is there any place where the different jQuery structures, formats, and syntax is concised on a single page? If one does not know the name of the syntax he is looking for, then there is no way to google for it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('<option/>', { value : "hej", text : "Hopp" })
```

actually creates this:

```
<option value="hej">Hopp</option>
```

It's a convenient shortform. The `jQuery` function (mostly called through its alias `$`) is very versatile. Look it up: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

It's called `jQuery( html, props )`

Comment: For future reference, here’s the relevant quote from that page: “`jQuery(html, props)` → `props` is a map of attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element `html`.”

Comment: Thank you Atornblad. Does this shortform have a name?

Comment: Don't think so. It's really just a call to a function with two arguments - one string and one object...